# Is there a portable, convenient way to canonicalize relative paths?

Tags: zsh

Here, by "canonicalization" I mean, basically, the process of converting a filepath to its simplest, or "canonical", form.  E.g., the canonical form of `/foo/.//bar/../baz/` would be `/foo/baz`.

For absolute paths, zsh's `:a` modifier does a good job at this:

```
% printf -- '%s\n%s\n' "${WILDABSPATH}" "${WILDABSPATH:a}"
/foo/.//bar/../baz/
/foo/baz
```

Unfortunately, for relative filepaths, the `:a` modifier does too much, since it converts the filepath to an absolute one.

```
% printf -- '%s\n%s\n' "${WILDRELPATH}" "${WILDRELPATH:a}"
./foo/.//bar/../baz/
/tmp/foo/baz
```

Using the last example, is there a good way to convert `${WILDRELPATH}` to `foo/baz`?

---

I suppose that one answer to my question could be something like

```
[[ ${ORIGINAL} == /* ]] \
  && CANONICAL=${ORIGINAL:a} \
  || CANONICAL=${${ORIGINAL:a}#$PWD/}
```

Is there anything simpler?

Comment: can you use `realpath` for this? Somethin like `realpath -m --relative-to=./ ./foo/.//bar/../baz/` which outputs `foo/baz`

Answer (score 1):

I believe something to solve this will be using `realpath`.

You can do the following...

```
realpath -m --relative-to=./ ./foo/.//bar/../baz/ # Outputs foo/baz
# or
realpath -m /foo/.//bar/../baz/ # Outputs /foo/baz
```